# Perl: Is it possible to dynamically fix compile time error?

Tags: perl

If I have, for example, next perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print $x;
```

When I run this script, compilation will fail with error:

```
Global symbol "$x" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $x"?) at ...
```

**Is it possible to write some perl module which will be called when this error occur and automatically fix this error and continue compilation?** (Even links to any info is OK)

```
# This code is incorrect. 
# Here I just ask about such ability
# This code is very weak approximation how it might look
package AutoFix;

sub fix {
    $main::x =  'You are defined now';
}

1;
```

So next code will not fail and print `You are defined now`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use AutoFix;

print $x;
```

Comment: @toolic: Yes, I know. I want to trigger some function in `AutoFix` module. Like `NOT NULL` database constraint trigger `Default`

Comment: @ikegami: That is just demonstration of the problem. Question is: is it possible to fix compilation error or not?

Comment: No. And it doesn't make sense to. By definition, a compilation error is an inability to understand the intent of the programmer. How you can automatically fix something you don't understand?

Comment: Seeing as your AutoFix doesn't even attempt to fix the compilation error --`print $x;` still fails to compile even if `AutoFix::fix()` is called-- this SCREAMS [XY Problem](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). Voting to close for lack of clarity.

Comment: adding a package name is almost always the wrong way to fix this error.

Comment: Are you looking for something like the auto fix behaviors in VS Code?  Most of the the fixers in that context are responding to linter issues rather than compiler errors.  You can use perltidy to autoformat your code and PerlCritic to lint your code.

Comment: @ikegami: Of course my `AutoFix::fix` is not correct. In the question I just ask about such ability and do not know correct way of fixing this even do not know if this is possible at all.

Comment: @ysth: Yes, I know. This just a question how it might look. I have updated text;

Comment: @Eugen Konkov, Re "*do not know correct way of fixing this*", I've already pointed out it's impossible on a few different levels, and that you should state the problem you are actually trying to solve.

Comment: yes, please ask a new question with the actual circumstances you have; there will likely be a solution that isn't autofixing compile errors

Comment: @ikegami: Ok. I agree with you that this is probably not possible or too complex at current state of things. But this does not mean question is bad ;-)

Comment: @ysth: I added an answer how I resolve my problem currently.

Comment: None of the reasons I gave for it making no sense are limited to the current state. They would apply to all other states too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How much work would you like to do to create the code that could figure out what the fix should be? And, will that amount of work be comparable or less to the work required to examine code by hand?

Now, I'm writing all of this having spent quite a bit of time trying to come up with a system to analyze CPAN installer output to figure out what went wrong (a major impetus for CPANPLUS, now relegated to history). It's easy to tell that something is not right, but beyond that is a lot of suffering.

In your example, you have an error about an undeclared variable. How does AutoFix know if that should be a package or a lexical variable? You can guess one or the other, but you actually have two big problems:

- What is the intent of the code?
- Does the code reflect the actual intent?

Determining the intent of the code is often very difficult for even an experienced human programmer to figure out (just read StackOverflow question comments). Compiling code is often not correct code, in the sense that it doesn't achieve the desired outcome. Furthermore, does the programmer even understand the problem? Does the code the programmer wrote (incorrectly here) reflect the actual work the code should do? It's difficult for humans in code review to figure this out. Tools like [Coverity](https://scan.coverity.com) can guess at problems it knows about, but they aren't going to be able to correct the code.

But let's say that the programmer understands the problem. Have they correctly expressed that? The longer you've been programming, the more you lean toward "no", in general, in my experience.

This is completely different than the database constraint you mentioned. That's a narrowly targeted fix for an expected and allowed situation. Consider a different parallel: if the record has a New York area code but a Chicago address, should I fix the city? When I was a younger dumbass, I did a similar thing to a database. It was stupid because I thought I knew something I didn't, and everyone who understood the situation recognized it immediately. Even then, those sorts of constraints are how we model what we know about the world, not what the world actually is.

Now, to make AutoFix, you need to make something that can look at code, understand it, and figure out what it should do. You can make guesses, but you have no basis for playing the probabilities there.

Technical matters can't solve this. AutoFix can undo the work of pragmas such that some classes of errors don't show up, but so what? The program with an error just continues? How does that help anyone?

Not only that, compilers tend to complain when they realize they can't parse something. What they complain about is often not the problem. The first thing I teach people while debugging is that they need to look at the statement immediately proceeding the line line number in the error message. Any error message you catch can have a virtually infinite number of causes.

Consider this code, which fails in the same way as your example (same error message) but for a completely different but common reason:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $x = 5,
print $x++;
```

How do you figure out what the fix should be? It's not about declaring `$x`.

So, you now have two cases, and you build that your fixer. Then you encounter another case, so you build that in. And you keep doing this until eventually you have a large dictionary of fixes. Maybe you get a bit crazy and do some machine learning (and wouldn't a corpus of bad code and resolutions be cool).

But, the program still can't continue. It has to start over because it has to at least back up to where it should have done something but didn't. You can't merely restart the program because you don't know if its idempotent. Re-runing the program might redo work it shouldn't, such as inserting duplicate into databases.

Having said all that, this sort of thing is related to static analysis and the [refactoring browser](https://refactory.com/refactoring-browser/). Adam Kennedy's Parse Perl Isolated (PPI) project was a first step into understanding Perl code without compiling it, then move toward the Smalltalk ideal of understanding which parts of code represented the same thing. If you knew that two things named `foo` were the same thing, you could rearrange code dealing with `foo`. For example, if you renamed a method from `bar` to `set_bar`, you could immediately know which `bar`s you should rename and which belonged to some other class.

Adam wrote [Acme::BadExample](https://metacpan.org/pod/Acme::BadExample) and challenged anyone to get it to run. He wrote "any given piece of Perl source exists in bizarre pseudo-quantum-like state, in that it demonstrates both duality and indeterminism."

Jos Boumans stepped up and used some mind-bending Perl, which he then showed in [Barely Legal XXX Perl](https://www.slideshare.net/cdman83/barely-legal-xxx-perl-presentation), which I think he first presented in 2006. He was amazingly creative in his solutions, and in a way that I wouldn't want in production code.

Perl doesn't even know, by design, what type of thing will be in a variable or even that the method you might call on it will exist. In fact, it defers so much to the runtime, trusting that things will be in place by the time you need them, that we often say "only Perl can parse perl". You literally need to be able to run Perl code to properly compile it since `BEGIN` blocks can affect the parse. For example, a `BEGIN` can define a subroutine with a certain arity. How do you parse `foo 5, 6`? You have to know what has already been defined.

Perl has other "action at a distance" features that make this even tougher. `autodie` redefines CORE features to add extra behavior, but you might not be able to see that in the code. You can set default regex flags (and I've seen plenty of big screw ups by people applying `/isxm` to entire files without checking).

Answer (score -1):

As noted above, autofixing compile time error is not possible (or probably hard to fix)
Instead of fixing compile time error try to resolve your problem in different way.

For example. In your script you use `$x` variable. Probably you know that you will use it and you want to get instance of some value, e.g. `You are defined now` then you could use `Exporter`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use AutoFix qw/ $x /;

print $x;
```

And `AutoFix` module will look like:

```
package AutoFix;
require Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( $x $y $z );  # symbols to export on request

... # code which will create instance of $x $y $z on request

1;
```

Gool luck ;-)

Comment: Instead of adding AutoFix, why don't you just fix the code? You have to modify it anyway.